# PLEASE HELP E: failed to mount /cache (No such file or directory)

Tags: boot, boot-loop, fastboot, stock-rom, karbonn

I have a problem every time I turn on my phone (Karbonn Sparkle V) and I tried to google to solution and I couldn't find any

```
E: failed to mount /efs (No such file or directory)
E: failed to mount /system (No such file or directory)
# MANUAL MODE #
-- Appling Multi-CSC...
E: failed to mount /system (No such file or directory)
can't mount '/system' (No such file or directory)
E: failed to mount /cache (No such file or directory)
can't mount '/cache' (No such file or directory)
E: failed to mount /cache (No such file or directory)
E: can't mount /cache/recovery/last_recovery
E: failed to mount /data (No such file or directory)
E: Can't mount /data/log/recovery_log.txt
E: failed to mount /system (No such file or directory)
E: Can't mount /cache/recovery/log
E: Can't open mount /cache/recovery/log
(These errors then repeat in various order)
```

Please do help as soon as possible!

Comment: Seems like data on the eMMC chip is corrupted. You should flash this phone.

Comment: @esQmo How to do flash ? what things i have to do? please explain me in brief!

Comment: I have drivers for marshmallow 6.0.1. I don't know about flash files and flashing s/w. can you suggest one or two? @esQmo

Answer (score 1):

Your phone is a Mediatek device. So you need flash files with Scatter and SP Flashtool for flashing. You can get all [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/sparkle-v/general/stock-firmware-t2889509)

Edit:

Steps below are for flashing Mediatek devices using SP Flashtool and a Windows computer:

**What you'll need**:

- Download your device ROM files. You can find it [here](http://oceanhost.eu/pfub96wtegkh/015427.zip.htm)
- Download SP Flashtool. Can be found [here](http://oceanhost.eu/iia4pb09lcei/SP_Flash_Tool_exe_windows_v5.1424.00.rar.htm)
- Download [Mediatek drivers](https://androidmtk.com/download-mtk-usb-all-drivers), or [here](https://www.cyanogenmods.org/forums/topic/download-and-install-mediatek-usb-vcom-driver-on-windows-10/) (for Windows 10)

**How you'll do it**:

Downloaded files should be ziped (rar, zip or 7z format), unzip then proceed by installing the drivers and . Also unzip SP Flashtool and the ROM file to somewhere you can access quickly - say in the Desktop.

1. Go to the SP Flashtool folder and launch it. SP Flashtool opens on **Download** tab. On `Scatter-Loading` field, click on **Choose**. 
   This will open a file selector dialog. Browse to the folder where ROM files are located. Select the scatter file. Flashtool should load all files now.
   [image]
2. Click on the drop-down list and choose `Format All + Download`
   [image]
3. Now power off the device. Click on `Download` then connect the device to the computer with a USB cable.

Flashing should start and simply wait for the software do its things.

The flashing ends when the green check mark pops up.

Note: *This can be also solved by flashing a custom recovery, such as TWRP and manually mount the partitions*.

Comment: Warning: Do **not** *Format All + Download* Mediatek devices https://blog.hovatek.com/so-whats-all-this-talk-about-meditek-secure-boot-and-da-files

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. However that article focuses more on MTK devices with Secure Boot. Wasn't common in the time this question was answered.

Comment: Sure, didn't notice the date. Kindly update your answer. It is never good idea even on old devices with no secure boot you still lose device specific IMEI, Mac address, calibration data etc (see [#464](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/infinix-hot-8-x650c-root-twrp-un-bricking-custom-rom.3986799/post-82907489), [#470](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/infinix-hot-8-x650c-root-twrp-un-bricking-custom-rom.3986799/post-83358537))

Comment: When you're dealing with issue like corrupted partition table, Download Only or Firmware update don't fix such issue which is/was very common on old MTK chips. So You had to Format All + Download. Never lost IMEI or MAC Address doing this. And this is something I do for a living.

Comment: Also repairing IMEI on MTK is easier and can be done in seconds