# I cant find firmware for RCA Tab voyager android go edition

Tags: rom-flashing, system-error

In my tab's recent update it does run to problem the first thing I got was the tab never opens to the main screen(ui) it just stacked to manufacture logo page then after a week instead of stacking it start showing [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/174137/please-help-e-failed-to-mount-cache-no-such-file-or-directory) kind of error [image]
the thing I planned to do was flashing it unfortunetlly I cant find the same firmware as in my tab I searched and got http://gofirmware.com/post/rca-voyager-rct6873w42bmf8 still it doesn't work the download button is full of redirection instead of providing download link.
So finally, the idea it came to my mind was to download and flash the nearest version and model possible from [android MTK](https://androidmtk.com/download-rca-stock-rom-for-all-models) then I selected rct6873w42m f7 which has the nearest android v(7.0) .
however the problem are still there while flashing

[image]
I have tried: rebooting, repluging usb, removing batteries but none of it work
it kinda showing the version are not meting
what should i do now?

models:

- android v : android go edition with v8.1 (oreo)
- tab model/v: RCA voyager model
- rct6873w42bmf8; from the boot page
- rct6873w42; from the back of the tab

Comment: your device has problem with cache + para partitions. no need to flash another ROM, no ROM will work without these partitions. *"wipe cache partition"* might recreate cache partition, did you try?

Comment: @alecxs actually yeah , but no luck! heres the log https://linksharing.samsungcloud.com/dBhK4LKEy1qW#/

Comment: recommend to double check scatter file matches partition sizes from fastboot getvar all, then flash cache partition only

Comment: the best source for stock ROM is your device. do a read back https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220584 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203283